# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, gradle, android-edittext, inflate-exception

I am trying to make a login page using default Android Template.
Following is my code for layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.login.app.logintest.LoginActivity">

    <!-- Login progress -->
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/login_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

But I am getting Inflation Exception at EditText of email.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.login.app.logintest/com.login.app.logintest.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class EditText
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class EditText
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
```

Please suggest solution.
FYI I am using gradle version 2.1 in Android Studio.

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: which version of design library are you using??

Comment: why you need android:imeActionLabel in xml ?    use setImeActionLabel instead in code  editText.setImeActionLabel(getString(R.string.xxx), EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);   Similarly are you intending to do defined in this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using android:imeActionLabel in xml file, try to move it into Java code like this

```
editText.setImeActionLabel(getString(R.string.your_string), EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);
```

If you are not intending to do predefined action with IME option's then better to avoid `android:imeActionId` , `android:imeActionLabel` and `android:imeOptions` . For more info check [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using **android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText**

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                ............ />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Make sure that you are using design library above 22.2.1 like below:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```